# Search fast an element in array of java.util.LinkedList

Tags: java

Hey I am searching for a better method to search a String element in an array of LinkedLists.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m = 1000;
    LinkedList<String>[] arrayOfList = new LinkedList[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arrayOfList[i] = new LinkedList<>();
    }
}
```

This is my search method:

```
public int search(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfList[i].size(); j++) {
            if (arrayOfList[i].get(j).equals(word)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is how my LinkedLists look like:

```
Example output: arrayOfList[0] = [house,car,tree.....]
                arrayOfList[1] = [computer,book,pen....]
                ...... 
          until arrayOfList[1000] = [...]
```

My search method should find the index of my word. Example: search("computer") = 1; search("house") = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, a classic!

LinkedList is notoriously bad for random access, i.e. the list.get(j) method.
It's much better at iterating through the list, so it can jump from each item to the next item.

You could use list.iterator(), but the foreach loop does the same thing:

```
public int search(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (String listValue: arrayOfList[i]) {
            if (listValue.equals(word)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer notes that you can get much better performance by iterating over each `LinkedList` rather than using `List.get`. That's because `List.get` has to search from the start of the list each time. For example, if the `LinkedList` has 100 elements, then on average each call to `List.get(j)` will have to iterate over 50 elements, and you're doing that 100 times. The foreach loop just iterates over the `LinkedList` elements once.

The foreach strategy runs in O(n) time, that is, the time required to perform the lookup increases proportional to n, the total number of words, because you have to search them all for each word.

If you're going to be doing this a lot, and you can use data structures other than `LinkedList`, then you should iterate through your array of `LinkedList` once and build a `HashMap` where the key is the word and the value is the number of the array in which that word appears. Setting up this `HashMap` will require O(n) time, but subsequent lookups will only require O(1) time, meaning a constant time regardless of the number of words involved. So if you're going to do more than a single lookup, creating the `HashMap` will have better performance in big-O terms, although for a very small number of lookups (2 or 3) it may still be faster to scan the arrays.

You can build a `HashMap` like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> index = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (String word: arrayOfList[i]) {
        index.put(word, i);
    }
}
```

Now `search` just becomes:

```
public int search(String word) {
    return index.getOrDefault(word, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the strings are constructed in your program and how often you call the search method, testing on your strings' hash code can improve the performance. ex:

```
public int search(String word) {
    int wordHashCode = word.hashCode();
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (String listValue: arrayOfList[i]) {
            if (listValue.hashCode() == wordHashCode && listValue.equals(word)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```